# What is the alternative available for replacing mule and jetty in the below webservice?

Tags: mule, jetty

I need to move out of mule and jetty/jersey in my web service. I'm looking for a alternative way to implement the current code.

I'm starting the service like this -

org.mule.MuleServer -config deploy_jetty_jersey.xml

### deploy_jetty_jersey.xml

http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/jetty/2.2 
            http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/jetty/2.2/mule-jetty.xsd
                        http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/core/2.2
                        http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/core/2.2/mule.xsd
            http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/jersey/2.2
                        http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/jersey/2.2/mule-jersey.xsd
                        http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/vm/2.2
                        http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/vm/2.2/mule-vm.xsd">

```
<jetty:connector name="httpConnector" useContinuations="true"
    configFile="jettyConfig.xml" />
<jetty:endpoint address="http://localhost:8080" name="serverEndpoint"
    path="html" synchronous="false" />

<model name="ServiceSample">
    <service name="testComponent">
        <inbound>
            <jetty:inbound-endpoint ref="serverEndpoint" />
        </inbound>
    </service>

    <service name="restTestHello" initialState="started">
        <inbound>
            <inbound-endpoint address="jersey:http://localhost:7003/rest"
                synchronous="true" />
        </inbound>
        <component>
            <singleton-object class="com.rest.RestResource" />
        </component>
    </service>
</model>
```

### jettyConfig.xml

```
<Set name="handler">
    <New id="Handlers" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
            <Array type="org.mortbay.jetty.Handler">
                <Item>
                    <New id="Contexts" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection" />
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.DefaultHandler" />
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <New id="StaticHandler" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ResourceHandler" />
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler">
                        <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
                        <Set name="resourceBase">
                            <SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="." />
                            XXXXXX
                        </Set>
                        <Call name="addHandler">
                            <Arg>
                                <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ResourceHandler" />
                            </Arg>
                        </Call>
                    </New>
                </Item>
            </Array>
        </Set>
    </New>
</Set>
<Call name="addLifeCycle">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.WebAppDeployer">
            <Set name="contexts">
                <Ref id="Contexts" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="webAppDir">XXX</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>

<Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
<Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
<Set name="sendDateHeader">true</Set>
<Set name="gracefulShutdown">1000</Set>
```

I need an alternate software which uses similar xml structure, so that there will be minimal java change.

Comment: Asking open ended questions for recommendations are really not that suitable for stackoverflow.  What have you tried?  Why is it not working?

Comment: You are using `org.mortbay.jetty` which is an ancient and long ago EOL (End of Life) version of Jetty.  The [Jetty project moved to Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) about 10 years ago, and is still being maintained on the `org.eclipse.jetty` namespace.  Latest version is `9.4.15.v20190215`.

Comment: Also Mule 2.2 is an ancient and obsoleted version.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious alternative would be to move to a newer Mule version and replace the jetty connector with an HTTP Listener. If you define your REST API with a RAML file you can also use APIKit routing and validation.